# Почему многоточная программа не завершает своё выполнение в Java?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Создаем абстрактный класс `IntGenerator`, в котором объявляем `volatile` переменную типа `boolean` с именем `canceled`, содержащий минимум методов:

- `next()` - генерирует следующее случайное число в диапазоне [-100;100];
- `setCanceled()` - устанавливает флаг отмены дальнейших операций (см. далее).

**Немного теории**
Так как переменная с именем `canceled` имеет тип `boolean`, следовательно она **атомарна** (простые операции -  такие, как присваивание и возвращение значения, - не прерываются при выполнении).

**Идём дальше**
Создаем класс `EvenChecker`, который будет являться потоком (простыми словами) и будет проверять объекты, унаследованные от абстрактного класса, у которых метод `next()` сгенерирует **нечетное** число, установит флаг отмены дальнейших операций `private volatile boolean canceled = false` и дальнейшие операции с объектами должны прекратиться. Но почему они не прекращают своё выполнение?

Вывод на консоль (программа полностью отрабатывает в 10 потоков):

```
Current value: -60; EvenChecker id: 1 ; thread: by.company.test.thread.generator.EvenChecker@10818b83
Current value: -66; EvenChecker id: 4 ; thread: by.company.test.thread.generator.EvenChecker@3e369c7a
Current value: 68; EvenChecker id: 0 ; thread: by.company.test.thread.generator.EvenChecker@3fef7d6b
Current value: 87; EvenChecker id: 3 ; thread: by.company.test.thread.generator.EvenChecker@26972cd
Current value: 99; EvenChecker id: 4 ; thread: by.company.test.thread.generator.EvenChecker@3e369c7a
Current value: -65; EvenChecker id: 1 ; thread: by.company.test.thread.generator.EvenChecker@10818b83
# Value: 99 not even! EvenChecker id: 4 ; thread: by.company.test.thread.generator.EvenChecker@3e369c7a
Current value: 84; EvenChecker id: 6 ; thread: by.company.test.thread.generator.EvenChecker@3ea94c2c
Current value: 47; EvenChecker id: 6 ; thread: by.company.test.thread.generator.EvenChecker@3ea94c2c
# Value: 47 not even! EvenChecker id: 6 ; thread: by.company.test.thread.generator.EvenChecker@3ea94c2c
# Value: 87 not even! EvenChecker id: 3 ; thread: by.company.test.thread.generator.EvenChecker@26972cd
Current value: 1; EvenChecker id: 9 ; thread: by.company.test.thread.generator.EvenChecker@2ba4169e
Current value: 66; EvenChecker id: 5 ; thread: by.company.test.thread.generator.EvenChecker@313c67b1
Current value: -41; EvenChecker id: 2 ; thread: by.company.test.thread.generator.EvenChecker@74ecfb18
Current value: -92; EvenChecker id: 0 ; thread: by.company.test.thread.generator.EvenChecker@3fef7d6b
# Value: -41 not even! EvenChecker id: 2 ; thread: by.company.test.thread.generator.EvenChecker@74ecfb18
Current value: 1; EvenChecker id: 5 ; thread: by.company.test.thread.generator.EvenChecker@313c67b1
# Value: 1 not even! EvenChecker id: 9 ; thread: by.company.test.thread.generator.EvenChecker@2ba4169e
Current value: 58; EvenChecker id: 8 ; thread: by.company.test.thread.generator.EvenChecker@2596c990
Current value: -59; EvenChecker id: 7 ; thread: by.company.test.thread.generator.EvenChecker@2e20fe65
# Value: -65 not even! EvenChecker id: 1 ; thread: by.company.test.thread.generator.EvenChecker@10818b83
# Value: -59 not even! EvenChecker id: 7 ; thread: by.company.test.thread.generator.EvenChecker@2e20fe65
Current value: -12; EvenChecker id: 8 ; thread: by.company.test.thread.generator.EvenChecker@2596c990
# Value: 1 not even! EvenChecker id: 5 ; thread: by.company.test.thread.generator.EvenChecker@313c67b1
Current value: -18; EvenChecker id: 0 ; thread: by.company.test.thread.generator.EvenChecker@3fef7d6b
Current value: 51; EvenChecker id: 8 ; thread: by.company.test.thread.generator.EvenChecker@2596c990
Current value: -68; EvenChecker id: 0 ; thread: by.company.test.thread.generator.EvenChecker@3fef7d6b
# Value: 51 not even! EvenChecker id: 8 ; thread: by.company.test.thread.generator.EvenChecker@2596c990
Current value: -88; EvenChecker id: 0 ; thread: by.company.test.thread.generator.EvenChecker@3fef7d6b
Current value: -32; EvenChecker id: 0 ; thread: by.company.test.thread.generator.EvenChecker@3fef7d6b
Current value: 86; EvenChecker id: 0 ; thread: by.company.test.thread.generator.EvenChecker@3fef7d6b
Current value: -64; EvenChecker id: 0 ; thread: by.company.test.thread.generator.EvenChecker@3fef7d6b
Current value: -47; EvenChecker id: 0 ; thread: by.company.test.thread.generator.EvenChecker@3fef7d6b
# Value: -47 not even! EvenChecker id: 0 ; thread: by.company.test.thread.generator.EvenChecker@3fef7d6b

===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


Process finished with exit code 0
```

**class** `IntGenerator`:

```java
public abstract class IntGenerator {
    private volatile boolean canceled = false;

    public void setCanceled() {
        canceled = true;
    }

    public boolean isCanceled() {
        return this.canceled;
    }

    public abstract int next();
}
```

**class** `SimpleGenerator`:

```java
public class SimpleIntGenerator extends IntGenerator {
    @Override
    public int next() {
        return (int) (Math.random()*(200+1)) - 100;
    }
}
```

**class** `EvenChecker`:

```java
public class EvenChecker implements Runnable {
    private final IntGenerator generator;
    private final int id;

    public EvenChecker(IntGenerator generator, int id) {
        this.generator = generator;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!generator.isCanceled()) {
            int value = generator.next();
            System.out.println("Current value: " + value + "; " +
                    "EvenChecker id: " + id +
                    " ; thread: " + this);

            if(value % 2 != 0) {
                System.out.println("# Value: " + value + " not even! " +
                        "EvenChecker id: " + id +
                        " ; thread: " + this);
                generator.setCanceled();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Запускаем через TestNG:**

```java
@Test
    public void runEvenChecker() {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        // SimpleIntGenerator generator = new SimpleIntGenerator(); - так тоже не выходит
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            SimpleIntGenerator generator = new SimpleIntGenerator();
            executorService.execute(new EvenChecker(generator, i));
        }
    }
```

Цитата из книги:

> Ключевое слово volatile также обеспечивает видимость изменений в приложении. Если поле объявляется с ключевым словом volatile, это означает, что сразу же после записи в это поле все операции чтения «увидят» изменение. Это утверждение истинно даже при использовании локальных кэшей — volatile-поля немедленно записываются в основную память, и чтение выполняется из основной памяти.

Comment: В чем ошибка, непонятно?

Comment: @RomanC, в абстрактном классе `IntGenerator` создается `volatile` переменная, а это, исходя из информации в книге Шилдта, означает то, что она создается в одном экземпляре для множества созданных потоков и все потоки пользуются только одним экземпляром данной переменной.

Comment: Переменная создается *всегда* в одном экземпляре, если конечно не считать количество экземпляров класса. Умные книжки надо читать внимательно.

Comment: @RomanC, если вы глянете код, то видно, что создается несколько экземпляров класса. Про `всегда` никто и ничего не говорил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас для каждого потока создается свое экземпляр `SimpleIntGenerator`, поэтому отмена в одном потоке никак не влияет на другие.

Вынесите создание за цикл:

```
SimpleIntGenerator generator = new SimpleIntGenerator();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    executorService.execute(new EvenChecker(generator, i));
}
```

Важно только понимать, что выход из каждого конкретного потока произойдет тогда, когда поток придет в точку проверки флага `cancelled`. В частности это означает, что если поток уже зашел в цикл, то он спокойно себе сгенерирует новое значение с помощью генератора, как можно наблюдать в этом запуске (я добавил вывод id в `EvenChecker.toString` для наглядности):

```
Current value: 85; EvenChecker id: 0 ; thread: EvenChecker [id=0]
Current value: 79; EvenChecker id: 2 ; thread: EvenChecker [id=2]
# Value: 79 not even! EvenChecker id: 2 ; thread: EvenChecker [id=2]
Current value: -72; EvenChecker id: 7 ; thread: EvenChecker [id=7]
# Value: 85 not even! EvenChecker id: 0 ; thread: EvenChecker [id=0]
Current value: 10; EvenChecker id: 3 ; thread: EvenChecker [id=3]
Current value: -62; EvenChecker id: 5 ; thread: EvenChecker [id=5]
Current value: 48; EvenChecker id: 6 ; thread: EvenChecker [id=6]
Current value: -83; EvenChecker id: 1 ; thread: EvenChecker [id=1]
Current value: 12; EvenChecker id: 4 ; thread: EvenChecker [id=4]
# Value: -83 not even! EvenChecker id: 1 ; thread: EvenChecker [id=1]
```

Тут нечетное значение сгенерировал поток `2`, но потоки `7, 0, 3, 4, 6, 1, 4`, очевидно, уже вошли в цикл. И удачно сгенерировали следующие значения.  Остальные потоки еще не успели войти в цикл, и вышли сразу же проверив флаг в условии while на первой же итерации.

Невозможно прервать поток моментально в произвольном месте. Всегда будет какая-то точка, где поток будет явно проверять флаг или выполнять interruptable операцию (типа `Thread.sleep`). И только в этих точках можно будет прервать выполнение потока, а до тех пор он будет исполняться.

Разница в выполнении кода, когда `generator` один и много в том, что когда их много, то каждый поток продолжает генерировать значение до тех пор пока не получит нечетное число. С одним же - поток выйдет, как только дойдет до проверки, при этом может сгенерировать еще максимум одно значение.

Если важно, чтоб "после" сигнала об остановке, поток ни при каких обстоятельствах не мог генерировать значения, то нужно менять реализацию. Главное договориться, что означает "после", т.к. тут операции выполняются параллельно и одни поток, скажем, ставит флаг, а второй в то же время на многоядерной системе генерирует значение, и нужна какая-то точка синхронизации, чтобы упорядочивать события из разных потоков.

Comment: Роман, вынес создание `SimpleIntGenerator` за цикл, но результат всё равно тот же.

Comment: Результат не такой же. Я добавил объяснение, что происходит и где ваши ожидания, скорее всего, не оправдываются.